# grep command over ssh remote box

Tags: bash, grep, rabbitmq

I am running script via  ssh commands on remote box

Script contains code as below

```
(sudo rabbitmqctl list_vhosts  -q | grep $RABBITMQ_BATCH_VHOST )
RESULT=$?
echo $RESULT
```

When $RABBITMQ_BATCH_VHOST  is valid present in list_vhosts the above command displays RESULT

but when $RABBITMQ_BATCH_VHOST is not present in list_vhosts this command doesnot print anything . Am I doing something wrong

Comment: show the full command. How do you execute the script? Is the bash option `set -e` set? `set -o pipefail` ?

Comment: cat script.sh  | ssh -i  $PEM_PATH  -o   "StrictHostKeyChecking no" $RABBITMQ_SSH_USER@$RABBITMQ_BATCH_HOST

Comment: The `RABBITMQ_BATCH_VHOST` is empty on the remote host, soyou execute `| grep )`. ssh doesn't "transfer" environment variables. Can you check by placing a simple `echo "$RABBITMQ_BATCH_VHOST"` in the script and see the output?

Comment: Its not empty if I print inside the script it prints the value as expected

Comment: Puff, then try running with the verbose `set -x`, ie. `cat script.sh | ssh ... bash -x`? You can inspect the bash options, ie. add `echo $-` in the script before the command and check the output of it. The `set -e` may make `grep` exit if it exists with non-zero exit status. Alternatively you can `( ... grep) && ret=0 || ret=$?` and see if the problem persists